# Can I still fly to Pakistan if my passport number on my Pakistan Origin Card does not match my current passport number?

Tags: air-travel, passports, pakistan, passport-renewals

Can I still fly to Pakistan if my passport number on my Pakistan Origin Card does not match my current passport number?

Comment: my last passport is cancelled so i have now new passport but i got a POC Card on my old passport. I have german citizenship. i got my Poc  Card in  december 2016. I do not have my old passport due to some reason i should have to give it back but i have copies of that.

Comment: Actually i got  german citizenship on october 2016 so after two weeks i got my german passport so right after i applied for my poc card. After i have done it all i got a letter that they did a mistake in my passport (mistake: on my birthplace they wrote my city and country which is for their rules is wrong it only have to be city not country) because of this small mistake i have to give my old passport back and get a new passport.

Comment: No. I have only copies of that passport.

Comment: AOA there, i also have now the same problem, got my new German Passport with different nr and now not matching the passport nr which the one on POC. Have someone any experience traveling to pakistan with? I do have my expired one though.
Thankx

Comment: Can I still fly to Pakistan if my passport number on my Pakistan Origin Card does not match my current passport number?I have only passport copy

Comment: @LuckyShah What did the Pakistan embassy/consulate in your country of residence say when you asked them?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can (but would be worth checking!) since there is no qualification of:

> - Seven years card validity (except foreign spouse)

at [High Commission for Pakistan London](http://www.phclondon.org/nadra/poc/apply/manually/#poc_req_docs). (The foreign spouse exclusion merely is to limit the validity to five years.)

Timatic is not very helpful with:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a Pakistan origin
>   card (POC) or a national ID card for overseas Pakistanis

since there is no mention of the numbers having to match (though lack of that is a good sign, in a way).

Answer (score 1):

In Pakistan there is no problem with the number bit.

In Germany on the Frankfurt airport they will ask why there numbers are not the same.
But when you have your old passport or a copy with you there is no problem anymore.

Comment: Please can you edit and add why you know what you just wrote? A link to an official website and a quote from that site will be great.